# Grunt tasks are slow in yeoman application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I have an angular project build with yeoman, talking to a rails api backend.

Everything works fine, except that grunt tasks are very slow.

When I run `grunt server --verbose`:

```
Execution Time (2014-01-15 13:37:55 UTC)
loading tasks         14.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 26%
server                  1ms  0%
preprocess:multifile   11ms  0%
clean:server           13ms  0%
concurrent:server     34.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 63%
autoprefixer            1ms  0%
autoprefixer:dist     369ms  ▇ 1%
connect:livereload     17ms  0%
watch                  5.8s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 11%
Total 54.8s
```

Some of my Gruntfile:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    ...
  });

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-preprocess');

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'preprocess:multifile',
      'clean:server',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test'
    //'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'preprocess:multifile',
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'ngmin',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);

};
```

Size of project:

```
vagrant@vm ~code/myapp/app/scripts
$> find -name "*.js" | xargs cat | wc -l
10209
```

I am running on MacOS 10.8 with i7 processor, 16GB ram, SSD... It is normal that is takes so long ? What makes the grunt task (and especially "loading tasks") so slow ?

**Note:** I am ssh'd inside a vagrant machine and running the grunt commands from there. If I run the grunt command on my native system, it's much faster (`loading tasks` takes 1.6s instead of 14.3).

So the shared filesystem might be an issue. But why...

Comment: I've got the same problem. Seems like imagemin takes forever (```grunt serve --verbose --debug``` exposed this). Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly same problem with Vagrant and Yeomans angular-generator. After running `grunt serve` it took almost 30 seconds to compile sass, restart server etc.

I already used NFS but it was still slow. Then I tried [jit-grunt](https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt/), just-in-time grunt loader. I replaced load-grunt-tasks with jit-grunt and everything is now a lot faster.

Here's a good article about JIT-Grunt:
https://medium.com/written-in-code/ced193c2900b

Answer (score 4):

I am using grunt inside a Vagrant virtualbox. (ubuntu 12.04). My native files are on my host machine (OSx). Because the grunt tasks are io-intensive, and they are run through file sharing, this make them quite slow.

This can be improved by adding nfs to Vagrant (http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html). This will make Vagrant share files with nfs instead of the default Vagrant file sharing. It will be a bit faster, but not much.

For comparison, on my machine:

For running the subtask `loading grunt tasks`

- natively: 1.2s
- with nfs: 4s
- vagrant file sharing: 16s

If only a specific task is taking a lot of time, this specific task might be the problem. To troubleshoot, use time-grunt: https://npmjs.org/package/time-grunt.

Comment: Thank you @pinouchon. This is exactly the problem I was having and your solution helped. Upping.

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues as well, and have found:

```
nospawn: true
```

To be the fastest option. I went from ~20s to ~1s to concat, minify, and uglify JS.

Comment: This. In my case, I had a browserify watch task running that would take 7 seconds to recompile on a change. After adding this (well, "spawn: false") to the options section of watch:browserify, it dropped down to a 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Yeoman's ngbp generator and Vagrant. Even with nfs, a simple change on a template took about 30s to be seen in the browser.

Using [jit-grunt](https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt/) caused time to be reduced to 10s. After using spawn:false, even though there was no reduction at the first load, changes took less than 1s (0.086s) to propagate to the browser! (Yes!)

The changes I've made to `Gruntfile.js`:

1. I commented all the grunt.loadNpmTasks but grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch') [That's because of a task rename ngbp does later on];
2. I added *require('jit-grunt')(grunt);* after grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
3. I added *spawn: false* to *delta: { options: {livereload: true, **spawn: false**} ...}*.

Comment: Changing this i went from 34 seconds for a large less file to 259ms.... That's just INSANE.